# Logging messages from Windows Service to Application via Named Pipes in WCF

Tags: c#, windows, wcf, service, named-pipes

I have a Windows Service which performs some data collection from a serial device connected to my PC. This Windows Service hosts a WCF service over named pipes which can then be used my one of my applications in order to query the serial data.

The problem is that I want to send log messages from the service to the application sometimes - for example I would like to send a log message to the application every time a certain value is received over the serial connection.

The WCF over named pipes is working really well for pulling service information from the application, but what I want to do is push some values from the service to the application every now and again in addition.

Any ideas?

AK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We solved this problem recently.
Our solution can be find at [flexbit.at (German)](http://www.flexbit.at/blog/wcf-duplex-zwischen-windows-sevice-und-gui-frontend/) with a downloadable [sample project](http://www.flexbit.at/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/ServiceGui.zip).
For further info you may contact [Daniel](http://daniellang.net/) - he solved this.

Comment: Wow...that is almost an identical problem! Time to see how good my German is...thanks!

Comment: Turns out this is a much more difficult task than I anticipated. I seem to be having some issues with the singleton, I'll have to create a couple of test projects I think to see where I am going wrong.

Comment: Could you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702379/queuing-in-oneway-wcf-messages-using-windows-service-and-sql-server ?

Comment: Hi, is it possible for you to email me the sample project zip file? the link for it got error.

Comment: The link to the solution is broken.  Please reset the link.